# Free email automation / workflow

Tags: web-apps, email, contact-manager, marketing

I'm looking for free software (or a web app that has a free tier that doesn't expire) that enables me to add users (i.e. email addresses) to a "workflow" / automation that contains a timeline with different branches of logic determining whether (and when) to send certain emails.

Each user will be on her own schedule in the series of emails. There can be different paths of if/else branching logic that check for the presence of "tags" associated with that user to determine which branch to proceed down (and therefore which emails to send).

I used to pay for an account at [ActiveCampaign](https://www.activecampaign.com/learn/guides/goals-marketing-automation/) which attempts to do exactly what I'm hoping for (see the screenshot of a sample workflow), but their service was unreliable.

[image]

I'm already aware of [Mautic](https://www.mautic.org/) (open-source PHP software) and have installed it but found it to be too buggy.

Basically, I'm looking for an alternative to ActiveCampaign, Mautic, and Infusionsoft (either free open-source software or a web app that has a free tier).

Comment: Did you write to both ActiveCampaign and Mautic and explain your problems? If they are not aware of them, it will be difficult for them to fix them. This many not help you today, but will help you and others further down the road. I would especially expect a for-pay service to work with you to resolve problems

Comment: @Mawg Yes, I did. I spent years with ActiveCampaign, and they didn't seem to care at all. Finally, when I *canceled* my subscription, a rep wrote to me who seemed to care, and he listened to my suggestions and says that he agrees and wants to improve their service and hopes to win my business again one day. Mautic has not seemed interested in feedback either.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, Ryan. Sounds liek you did what you could with them. I only hope that you get an answer here